# Как отформатировать код в IDEA по определенному знаку или позиции в коде?

Tags: intellij-idea, форматирование, форматирование-кода

Есть ли возможность в IDEA отформатировать код так чтобы было выравнивание по определенному знаку. Например по символу "="
т.е. чтобы вот такой код:

```
DailyRegValue = rs.getLong("dailyReg"),
                activeUsersValue = введите сюда кодrs.getLong("activeUsers"),
                payingUsersValue = rs.getLong("payingUsers"),
                subscriptionsValue = rs.getLong("subscriptions"),
                mrrValue = rs.getLong("mrr"),
                mrrAverageValue = rs.getLong("mrrAverage"),
                percentPayingUsersValue = rs.getLong("payingUsersPercentage"),
```

превратился в такой:

```
     DailyRegValue                              = rs.getLong("dailyReg"),
                        activeUsersValue        = rs.getLong("activeUsers"),
                        payingUsersValue        = rs.getLong("payingUsers"),
                        subscriptionsValue      = rs.getLong("subscriptions"),
                        mrrValue                = rs.getLong("mrr"),
                        mrrAverageValue         = rs.getLong("mrrAverage"),
                        percentPayingUsersValue = rs.getLong("payingUsersPercentage"),
```